# Booting from 18.04 DVD, I get red/white/black bars on screen

Tags: boot, video, 18.04

System is an older Dell 4 ram, MSI ATI Radeon 6450 grapics card (2560 x 1600 max).
Trying to boot from an Ubuntu 18.04 desktop DVD, I get alternating horizontal bars with various shades of red, about 1/3 white, and a couple of black. Arrow mouse pointer active.

Display is a Dell 2408WFP flat panel connected via DVI-D.

Any suggestions?